# Project Euler 58 - is there an anti-pattern in my solution?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on the [58<sup>th</sup> problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=58) from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

While my solution runs fine when I set the limit to 8%, it goes beyond one minute after that.

This surprises me, because I use a library for the primes generation and what I do by myself looks linear to me, and fine.

Though obviously I've missed plenty of huge thunks, quadratic (or worse) functions, bottlenecks etc before, and it must be the same here again.

What I'd like is a chek of my solution to know if the code is wrong, or if it's the way I handle the problem that's stupid. In the latter case, I'd like not to be spoiled.

I consider my question not to be a code review one, because basically my code doesn't work for its purpose, but I might be wrong, in which case please transfer the question to the appropriate SE site.

I tried literate programming for this one, so I'll just dump my file to provide further explanations.

### My .lhs (well, formatted for SO)

We don't handle the primes ourselves and we want help from the compiler.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Numbers.Primes
```

First, we construct in diags the stream of the numbers that are
on the diagonals. To do that, we notice that those numbers get incremented
4 times in a row by a certain number, and then again with this number + 2, etc.
replicate 4 [2, 4..] will give us a list of increments.

Then we just need to aggregate all that with a scanl (+) and there we have
our list.

```
primesDiags :: [Int]
primesDiags = go diags primes
  where
    diags = scanl (+) 1 . concatMap (replicate 4) $ [2, 4..] :: [Integer]
```

Once we have this list, we map all the numbers to 0 if the number is composite
and 1 if the number is prime. To do that efficiently, we use a library to
provide the stream of primes and map the two lists by running through them
once only.

```
    go dss@(d:ds) pss@(p:ps) | d < p = 0:go ds pss
                             | d > p = go dss ps
                             | otherwise = 1:go ds ps
```

Then we tell ghc we know why our pattern matching is incomplete

```
    go _ _ = undefined -- we operate on streams
```

Now we have everything we need to answer the problem. Next step is to find
at which square we cross the specific limit we seek to spot. To do that we
simply update an accumulator to represent the number of primes we met up
until this point and we keep track of the index of the square we're at too.

We start the recursion at 2 to just keep track of factorized behaviour.
That's why we skip one item in primesDiags and since this item is 1 we
set our acc to 0 (1 isn't prime).

```
nthSquare :: Int
nthSquare = go 2 (tail primesDiags) 0
  where
    go n (w:x:y:_:ds) primeN | 8 * primeN' < compositeN' = n
                             | otherwise = go (n + 1) ds primeN'
      where
        total = 4 * n - 3
        delta = sum [w, x, y]
        primeN' = primeN + delta
        compositeN' = total - primeN'
    go _ _ _ = undefined -- we operate on streams
```

Then, once we've spot the correct square, its side length
is obtained by doubling its index and substracting one.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ nthSquare * 2 - 1
```

[Here](http://hpaste.org/76528) is a paste if you want to play with the code.

Comment: one little nit: why is diags a `[Integer]` but primesDiag a `[Int]`?

Comment: because primesDiag contains only `0`s and `1`s (could have used booleans but ints allow me to use `sum` instead of `length . filter id`)

Comment: @Mog I think the point is "Why isn't `diags` also an `[Int]`?" - that makes both versions a bit faster.

Comment: Tangent: If you've formatted your code for SO, you can still get ghci to compile it which is [what I've been doing for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666723/i-taught-ghci-to-compile-my-stackoverflow-posts-can-i-make-it-slicker) but when I get round to it, I'll make a drop-in replacement for unlit, and support for this SO's style of literate programming will be slicker.

Comment: Replacing `[Integer]` with `[Int]` in the definition of `diags` reduced the run time from 33 secs to 27 secs on my machine.

Comment: @user5402 my rule of thumbs for the `Int`/`Integer` debate when doing some Euler problems is to always use `Integer` unless I know for sure that `Int` will not overflow for 32-bits systems, because I don't like a correct-only-if-executed-on-that-particular-system solution. Here I had no such knowledge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that the rest cannot be improved at all, but the library you used for prime generation isn't too fast. Using your code, I got

```
$./euler58 +RTS -s -RTS
11297
  30,958,460,200 bytes allocated in the heap
   4,671,021,104 bytes copied during GC
         495,832 bytes maximum residency (2822 sample(s))
          47,664 bytes maximum slop
               3 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     56551 colls,     0 par    5.96s    5.97s     0.0001s    0.0004s
  Gen  1      2822 colls,     0 par    1.60s    1.61s     0.0006s    0.0014s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time   21.47s  ( 21.50s elapsed)
  GC      time    7.56s  (  7.57s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   29.04s  ( 29.08s elapsed)

  %GC     time      26.1%  (26.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,441,874,868 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  73.9% of total user, 73.8% of total elapsed
```

Changing the import to

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes
```

(from the [`arithmoi`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package - disclaimer, I'm the author) and the first line of `primesDiags` to

```
primesDiags = go diags (map fromInteger primes)
```

the result is

```
$ ./aeuler58 +RTS -s -RTS
11297
   1,986,441,440 bytes allocated in the heap
      25,254,256 bytes copied during GC
         220,328 bytes maximum residency (34 sample(s))
         158,984 bytes maximum slop
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      3761 colls,     0 par    0.06s    0.06s     0.0000s    0.0002s
  Gen  1        34 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.96s  (  0.96s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.06s  (  0.06s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.02s  (  1.02s elapsed)

  %GC     time       5.9%  (5.9% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,064,058,991 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  94.1% of total user, 94.1% of total elapsed
```

which shows that your part of the code is decent. You can improve it by using the fact that on one of the spikes there are the squares, so that that needn't be considered at all.

Another point is that instead of computing all primes, you could just inspect the values on the diagonals (ignoring the squares) and check which of them are prime if you have a fast prime check. Whether that's faster depends on the prime check.

Comment: It seems strange to me that there's such a high quality requirement on the primes generation. Previous problems were solvable with my hand made stupid algorithm so it's kind of a big jump. Thanks though I didn't hear about your lib and it seems awesome. Though, right now it makes my system swap and freeze but if I edit my algo into a "more fold-like" type of thing it should be fine I guess :)

Comment: What makes your system swap and freeze? If you're referencing `primes` from different places, the list will be kept, since it's a CAF. For such cases, use `sieveFrom` to avoid sharing a huge list, or share the more compact list of `PrimeSieve`s and feed that to `primeList` where needed.

Comment: To be more precise, it swaps for a limit set to `10` instead of `8` (in the guard of the go function). edit post-you-comment: I'll look into it, thanks :)

Comment: Note that for the problem, you need 9, not 10. Edit: That said, even with 10, I get `Total   time   33.66s  ( 33.70s elapsed)` with `307,560 bytes maximum residency`.

Comment: Hum that's embarassing. I was calculating a primes/composites ratio while a primes/total ratio is needed. I guess that actually was the main problem. (well, not the main, but 10 is really out of reach with my former program while 9 isn't).

Comment: Well, that contributes, but with 9, `Data.Numbers.Primes.primes` takes three minutes here vs. 5 seconds for my sieve.

Comment: yup your lib is a great improvement, thanks a lot for the help, it's appreciated :)